# Scheduling app to open after 45. days using launchd

Tags: macos, plist, schedule, launchd

i'm making a launchd plist to open certain app after 45. days, however I'm stuck at Day and wondering why cron isn't supported anymore. 
Also would like to know if it is possible to restart "countdown" to opening app by unloading and loading the .plist file? Thanks in advance you for your answers.

Answer (score 0):

Use `StartCalendarInterval` in launchd plist file.

> **StartCalendarInterval** 
>        This optional key causes the job to be started every calendar interval as specified. Missing arguments
>        are considered to be wildcard. The semantics are much like crontab(5).  Unlike cron which skips job
>        invocations when the computer is asleep, launchd will start the job the next time the computer wakes
>        up.  If multiple intervals transpire before the computer is woken, those events will be coalesced into
>        one event upon wake from sleep.